# Clarification on Streaming and Effects in context of Pipes Library

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

The pipes tutorial have mentioned this in their documentation:

> If you sacrifice Effects you get Haskell's pure and lazy lists, which
> you can transform using composable functions in constant space, but
> without interleaving effects.
>
> If you sacrifice Streaming you get mapM,
> forM and "ListT done wrong", which are composable and effectful, but
> do not return a single result until the whole list has first been
> processed and loaded into memory.

But doesn't `Streaming` imply interlaved effects ? When you are `Streaming`, you actually consume chunk by chunk. So, while consuming chunk by chunk isn't the effects interleaved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streaming does indeed imply interleaved effects. The text you quote does not say otherwise.

To paraphrase the pipes documentation:

- If you don't have effects, then you're just left with lazy data structures. They compose nicely but you can't do IO (except lazy IO, which we're trying to avoid).
- If you do have effects but don't stream, then you can do IO but won't get a result until the end.